# Advantage of use of isolate over async in Dart

Tags: dart, asynchronous

I'm learning *isolate* in Dart, reading [the official tutorial](https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency). I don't understand, however, what the advantage of isolate over `async` is.

To see how isolates work, I wrote this simple code:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';

//generates many random numbers and returns the final result
Future<int> f({required int seed}) async {
  const numIter = 100000000;
  const upperBound = 10000;

  var r = Random(seed);
  for (var i = 0; i < numIter; ++i) {
    r.nextInt(upperBound); //just discards the result
  }
  return r.nextInt(upperBound);
}

void main() async {
  var sw = Stopwatch();
  sw.start();

  final future1 = f(seed: 0);
  // final future2 = Isolate.run(() async => f(seed: 1));
  // final future2 = f(seed: 1);
  print(await future1);
  // print(await future2);

  sw.stop();
  print(sw.elapsedMilliseconds.toString() + "(ms)");
}
```

The output is `685(ms)`.

If I un-comment these two lines,

```dart
// final future2 = f(seed: 1);
```

```dart
// print(await future2);
```

the output becomes `1338(ms)`, which is approximately the double of the previous `685(ms)`. Since dart is single-threaded (has only *main isolate* by default), this is expected. So far so good.

Then, if I instead un-comment these two lines,

```dart
// final future2 = Isolate.run(() async => f(seed: 1));
```

```dart
// print(await future2);
```

the output becomes `1304(ms)`. Why? I expect the output to stay around `600(ms)` because `Isolate.run()` introduces another thread of execution.

**Environment:** M1 Macbook. The code is run via `dart run` command.

Comment: `f` is not actually asynchronous.  It does all of its work immediately when you call it.  Dart executes asynchronous functions synchronously as much as it can (i.e. until the function reaches an `await`, which is syntactic sugar for returning a `Future`).  You therefore don't spawn the `Isolate` until after your first call to `f` has done all of its work.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you. Just putting `final future2 = Isolate.run(...)` BEFORE `final future1 = f(seed: 0)` made the executing time stayed around `600(ms)`, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@jamesdlin** is correct. Because `f()` is not actually asynchronous, the statement `final future1 = f(seed: 0);` blocks the main isolate before the second isolate is created.

You can see this with:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';

//generates many random numbers and returns the final result
Future<int> f({required int seed}) async {
  const numIter = 100000000;
  const upperBound = 10000;

  var r = Random(seed);
  for (var i = 0; i < numIter; ++i) {
    r.nextInt(upperBound); //just discards the result
  }
  return r.nextInt(upperBound);
}

void main() async {
  var sw = Stopwatch();
  sw.start();

  final future1 = f(seed: 0);
  print(sw.elapsedMilliseconds.toString() + "(ms)");
  final future2 = Isolate.run(() async => f(seed: 1));
  print(await future1);
  print(await future2);

  sw.stop();
  print(sw.elapsedMilliseconds.toString() + "(ms)");
}
```

Which outputs:

```
962(ms)
1124
4512
1946(ms)
```

The following modification will behave more along the lines of what you're expecting:

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:math';

//generates many random numbers and returns the final result
int f({required int seed}) {
  const numIter = 1000000000;
  const upperBound = 10000;

  var r = Random(seed);
  for (var i = 0; i < numIter; ++i) {
    r.nextInt(upperBound); //just discards the result
  }
  return r.nextInt(upperBound);
}

void main() async {
  var sw = Stopwatch();
  sw.start();

  final future1 = Isolate.run(() => f(seed: 0));
  final future2 = Isolate.run(() => f(seed: 1));
  print(await future1);
  print(await future2);

  sw.stop();
  print(sw.elapsedMilliseconds.toString() + "(ms)");
}
```

Comment: For my note: the reason why `f(seed: 0)` returns right away is async function doesn't mean "it always returns right away". As with normal (non-async) functions, it executes its body synchronously. Most examples of async functions found in tutorials for beginner deals with functions with small bodies (e.g. `Future<int> f() async { return Future.delayed(...); }`), so you may misunderstand "async function is magical in that it always return right away", but that's incorrect. The true reason is just that its body is very light (O(1) or so). Async functinos with larger body (as in OP) take time.